# How to use ember.js master with bower

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am working in an ember-cli project where I want to use the master branch of ember.js for [metal-views](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/5432).  I've gotten it to install the latest commit with the command below.

```
bower install 'git@github.com:emberjs/ember.js.git#0654413ee8dd2830dec18a4bbbc078826731d84d'
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when I run ember server.  It seems ember-cli expects a shim [repository](https://github.com/components/ember).  Is there a master shim repository or is there a way to get ember.js master to work with ember-cli?

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-canary-build-instead-of-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that newest canary build 1.8+ will start tracking ember metal-views. But you just have to make a few changes to your bower.json file to get metal-views. Again I believe that you can run off canary build. But this will work for now.

Remove: `"ember": "1.7.0"`

ReplaceWith: `"ember": "components/ember#metal-views"`

At the end of the add a `,` and append this to end the of file

Add: `"resolutions": {
        "ember": "metal-views"
      }`

Run Bower install from command line and you should be good.